# How can I tell if a fragment at world point has an opacity?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to figure out how can I extract opacity from fragment material at a specific point:

```
var renderProxy = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(
            viewer.model,
fragId);

renderProxy.material.opacity
```

Can I rely on this value to be reflect the fragment opacity?

#### EXPLANATION

When the user clicks on an object I'd like to know if it's transparent (a window for example).

AFAIK, an object can be partially transparent so I choose a point at the center of one of its faces (assuming quadrilateral, we have our own definition of 'center') to query for transparency.

Another way is casting a ray and ignore transparent objects to find intersection point and then test its distance from the face/plane of the object.

I'd like to know what is the most reliable way to do that?

Comment: Would you mind sharing more detail and the use case about what you want to do with this property?

Comment: @EasonKang edited the question, let me know if it is still unclear. Thanks!

Comment: After some research and finding, there is another way to determine whether the material of currently focused fragment is transparent or not, i.e. `material.transparent`. For example, if the target fragment is the window glasses, the value of the `material.transparent` is true and `material. opacity` is smaller than 1. Is this helpful for your cause?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks @EasonKang! just wanted to make sure that it was reliable.